# Rotate when already using an animation to rotate?

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, rotation

### The Problem

I'm creating a sword that 'swings' 90 degrees.
This is done using a Unity animation:
[image]

When a player attacks, such a sword is created. Depending on the player's direction, the sword will be mirrored across the X or Y axis.
But when the player attacks to the left, he attacks from the bottom and up, instead of opposite.

### Code

Here's the code I use to determine which way we should mirror the sword:

```
void changeDirection()
{
    print(Direction);
    if(Direction == Entity.direction.RIGHT)
        gameObject.transform.localScale = new Vector3(-1, 1, 1);
    if (Direction == Entity.direction.LEFT)
    {
        gameObject.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, -1, 1);
    }
    if (Direction == Entity.direction.DOWN)
        gameObject.transform.localScale = new Vector3(-1, -1, 1);
}
```

Up isn't here, because that's default.

### Why can't you just rotate it?

Because, the animation already rotates the sword, so it 'overwrites' whatever I do. That's my theory, at least.

### Video Example of Problem

http://a.pomf.se/vgxumj.webm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a child object to the Weapon_Swing transform, and spawn the sword in the child object. This should ensure that you can set the localRotation of the sword independent of the animation.

Answer (score 0):

I would create one animation file, pretty sure thats what you have already. Then parent it to other GameObject. Change direction of the parent game object in code.

Answer (score 0):

if(Direction == Entity.direction.RIGHT)

```
gameObject.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(90, 0, 1));
if (Direction == Entity.direction.LEFT)
{
     gameObject.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, 90, 1));
}
if (Direction == Entity.direction.DOWN)
     gameObject.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(90, 0, 1));
```

Comment: This does not work. First of all, why would you rotate the X or Y axis? We need to rotate the Z axis. Second, you cannot use rotate as I mentioned in the question, the rotation is 'overwritten' by the animation.

Answer (score 0):

For those in the future looking for an easy solution, LateUpdate appears to get called after the animation is applied, so any rotations done in LateUpdate don't get overwritten.